# Ending a modal run loop from an NSOperation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm performing a lengthy operation when my application starts up. I'm using a modal NSWindow to display my progress bar and messages throughout the operation.

What I want to accomplish is when the operation is done running, close the window automatically, and end the modal run loop and get on with the rest of the program. I've tried three different methods in my window controller:

**Method 1:**

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    // self.op is an initialized NSOperationQueue set before this method is called
    [self.op addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self performMigration]; // The method that does all the background work (works fine)
        [NSApp stopModal];
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [self close];
        }];
    }];
}
```

Result: The window stays on the screen until I move the mouse (or perform an 'event' of some sort) and then things continue like expected.

**Method 2:**

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [self.op addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self performMigration];
        [NSApp stopModal];
        [self close];
    }];
}
```

Result: The window closes, but the main run loop doesn't continue until a move the mouse (like above).

**Method 3:**

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    // Get the thread of the modal loop
    self.callbackThread = [NSThread currentThread];
    [self.op addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self performMigration];
        [self performSelector:@selector(callback) onThread:self.callbackThread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    }];
}

- (void)callback
{
    [NSApp stopModal];
    [self close];
}
```

Same result as #2.  I'm assuming (based on spending all day on this) that the modal run loop wants to be stopped during event handling (like pushing a Close button).

Is there something obvious that I'm missing to accomplish this seemly simple task?  Thanks!